# Passing variables with include?

Tags: php, variables, include

I want to pass variables with include, but it is not working...

File #1:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include '2.php';
$subject = "test";
echo ob_get_clean();
?>
```

File #2 (2.php):

```
    <?php echo ($subject); ?>
```

It's not passing. Advice? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You are not including `2.php` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, post edited to reflect properly.

Comment: `$subject` is not defined when you include.

Comment: `$subject` is undefined at the include point.

Answer (score 2):

An included PHP file is executed when it's included. You define `$subject` *afterwards*; it was undefined when you ran `2.php`.

Your code is essentially doing:

```
echo ($subject);
$subject = "test";
```

This will work fine:

```
$subject = "test";
include '2.php';
```

Comment: Side note: It looks like you're maybe taking a stab at making your own little templating engine. You might benefit from starting with an existing one, like Twig or Laravel and it's Blade engine.